# Content of slides of add-in file - VBA Powerpoint 2010

Tags: vba, add-in, powerpoint

I would like to create a PowerPoint 2010 add-in with many pre-prepared slides. It will have set of macros (+modification of UI), which will copy content of the slides from the add-in to the active presentation when button pressed.

Does anybody know how to get access to the content of the add-in slides from the macro?

Microsoft says that `Presentations( "my_addin.ppam" )` should do the work, see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743968%28v=office.15%29.aspx
To me it seems to be the easiest and preferred way. However, I am getting error message "Item my_addin not found in the Presentation collection."

The route via `Addins( "my_addin" )` does not seem to help either. Other way could be setting right variable while loading the add-in...?

Any help/point to the right direction highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1) There *are* no slides in an add-in file. You can't access what's not there. The add-in could insert slides from another PPT/PPTX file though.

2) It seems that the MSDN article you quote is wrong. On the other hand, you can iterate through the Addins collection, rather than the Presentations collection.

```
Sub ListAddins()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To AddIns.Count
        Debug.Print AddIns(x).FullName
    Next
End Sub

Sub TestGetAddin()
    Debug.Print GetAddin("showtimer").FullName
End Sub

Function GetAddin(sName As String) As AddIn
    Dim oAddin As AddIn
    For Each oAddin In AddIns
        If UCase(oAddin.Name) = UCase(sName) Then
            Set GetAddin = oAddin
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And on yet another hand that doesn't matter since the add-in PPA/PPAM won't have any slides in it.

But finally, knowing where the add-in is (fullpath or path properties will tell you that) would help you locate a regular PPT/PPTX file with your slides in it.